# Activation of Network Failed

Tags: wireless

I can connect to my Hotpots but cannot connect to my home WiFi can you help me.
I was able to connect when I first installed it but I cannot do it right now.

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: What does the command `nmcli device wifi connect WiFi_Name password WiFi_Password` in the terminal show? Replace the WiFi_Name and WiFi_Password with your WiFi's SSID and Password.